# Repel geom label and text in ggplot. And ordering geom points based on size

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have 2 data frames such as these:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  party = c("Blue Party", "Red Party"),
  dim1 = c(0.03, -0.04),
  dim2 = c(-0.05, 0.02),
  sz = c(34, 42)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  var = c("Economic", "Gov trust", "Inst trust", "Nationalism", "Religiosity"),
  dim1 = c(0.1, -0.5, 0, 0.6, 0.4),
  dim2 = c(0.1, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.3)
)
```

I want to plot the parties from `df1` as points defined by size and include arrows based on `df2` on the same graph. I've used `ggplot` to do this:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = dim1, y = dim2, color = party)) +
  geom_point(size = df1$sz) +
  scale_size_area() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = party),
                   box.padding   = 1,
                   point.padding = 1.5,
                   force = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=0, yend=0, x=dim1, y=dim2), data=df2,
    arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.20,"cm"), ends="first", type = "closed"), color="black") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, label=var),
    data = df2, color = "black", size = 3, force = 1)
```

Resulting in this:

[image: Graph 1]

The functions `geom_label_repel` and `geom_text_repel` prevent the party labels and the texts from overlapping, but how can I repel the labels and texts from each other?

My second problem is that I want to order the points, with the smallest in the front and the largest at the back. How could this be done?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: To reorder the points, this seems to work, `df1 <- df1[2:1, ]`. To see both points, maybe `geom_point(aes(alpha = 0.25), etc)`. To repel text and labels, in `geom_text_repel` maybe `nudge_y = -0.25`.

Comment: I need a more systematic way of doing this because I’m creating dozens of graphs with a for loop.