# How can I repel the label name from the plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have a boxplot graph where I want to show label names. The problem is that I want to repel these label names to make them beyond the boxplot. I tried `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel` package but it repels lables when they overlap each other.

Also tried advice like this: [Repel geom label and text in ggplot. And ordering geom points based on size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430041/repel-geom-label-and-text-in-ggplot-and-ordering-geom-points-based-on-size)

And have not received any comprehensive info about solving my problem.

Sample:

```
mtdata <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "name") %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl))

ggplot(mtdata, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text_repel(data = mtdata %>%
               filter(mpg > 20 & wt >3), aes(label = name))
```

Desirable output:

[image]

So, you can see that there is a dot which depicts exact label position and repelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheeky solution would be a simple nudge.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtdata <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "name") %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl))

ggplot(mtdata, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_boxplot() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(data = mtdata %>%
                    filter(mpg > 20 & wt >3), aes(label = name), nudge_x = .75)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, @tjebo! This one helped me. May be you also know whether it is possible to make lables fontface bold? I've tried ```theme(text = element_text(face="bold")``` but it did not work.

Comment: @k1rgas see maybe my answer to your previous question, I am sure you can do that with the ggtext package as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101889/how-can-i-rotate-labels-in-ggplot2/66102495#66102495 for future reference

Comment: ok, got you. Unfortunately, it does not fit me. But thanks!